# Taking time in Process.waitForExit() after exit ffmpeg console process

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I am working on video recording using `ffmpeg`. In that I am facing issue like after completion of video recording process `ffmpeg` console exit immediate but in application it is taking some time to get control in executing next statement. I am getting difference in `ffmpeg` execution time and process execution time.

Can anyone having idea why process execution taking time and how I can get the both value same. I start `ffmpeg` process as follow:

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("ffmpeg exe path", profile_new_parameters);
processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName("ffmpeg exe path");
```

Comment: r u using yourprocess.waitforexit() ?

Comment: Yes, but issue was resolved ;)

Comment: i am also using ffmpeg but it has some issue . my process stuck in waitforexit() .  my process of merging complete but it stuck in waitforexit() in some long audio and videos . can you tell me how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Actually we were getting delay issue while saving video recording time in DB, so resolved that issue by taking 2 threads in code..
both threads run simultaneously one by one on each 30 seconds(Used StopWatch) ..StopWatch class was useful for our scenario, we were started thread each 29 seconds instead of 30 seconds..

Comment: You can also try process.kill() or abort..

Comment: can you tell me why x11grab is not working , it show that x11grab unkown input format ?